# Biggest z-index but still "transparent"?

Tags: click, element, z-index, transparent

Is there a way to click through element, even if it's on top of the others. I have a link under one div, and the div must be where it is, but link should of course be clickable.

Solutions? Even jQuery is okay, if impossible with CSS.

Martti Laine

**EDIT:** I cannot add link higher, because the div here is a kind of overlay/glare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some Javascript you can add another `a` element with a higher z-index and absolutely position it over the location of the original link.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that will not result in hacking until the end of time is to either promote the link to a higher z-index or hide the div. Trying to track coordinates feels like an impossible solution.

Is there a reason you cannot promote the links to a higher stack index?

Comment: I added the reason to question.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this kind of thing before transmitting mouse coordinates with clicks and determining what was under the div, then sending a click to that element. But that was with only a few clickable items. I wouldn't want to do that for a complicated arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

add this css rule

```css
a {
    z-index: 999; /* greater than top most div */
}
```